# Fetch last five values from NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray, slice

I have a `NSMutableArray` whose count is 10 and I want to extract the last 5 values and store them in another array. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 6):

I think that `- (NSArray *) subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange%3a)) might help you.

```
NSRange theRange;
theRange.location = [wholeArray count] - 5;
theRange.length = 5;
NSArray *result = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:theRange];
```

**EDIT** : Be careful to check that your array has at least five elements, else, `subarrayWithRange` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use following way :

```
 NSMutableArray *first = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

    NSMutableArray *sec = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=5; i< [first count]; i++) {

        [sec addObject:[first objectAtIndex:i]];

     }

NSLog(@"sec - %@",sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subarrayWithRange method to get the desired arraydata. Try this hopefully it will work.

```
if (yourMutableArray.count > 10) 
{
NSArray *newArray = [yourMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(yourMutableArray.count-10, yourMutableArray.count-1)];
}
```